# Не работает :hover

Tags: css3, hover

Здравствуйте.

Не работает hover в коде, не могу понять, в чем дело.

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="foo">ссылка</a>
```

CSS

```
a.foo {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #9c3;
}

a.foo: hover {
    background: #697;
}
```

Comment: @Dmitry  Bryukhovetsky, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

Пробельчик лишний перед hover )

```
a.foo:hover{}
```

Comment: Вот черт) Все оказалось проще, чем я думал. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

все правильно,  :hover -- это псевдокласс. Они по-другому не пишутся.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/797157)

Comment: выше уже дано решение -- убрать пробел